# Remove duplicate rows based on column criterion python

Tags: python, pandas

I have following type of data set, I wish to remove all the rows which have the same ID and `group='DCM'`

```
    ID   date  group
0  3001  2010   DCM
1  3001  2012   NII
2  3002  2012   DCM
3  3002  2013   DCM
```

Resulting in:

```
    ID   date  group
0  3001  2010   DCM
1  3001  2012   NII
```

Here's how the database is created:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['3001','3001','3002','3002'], 'date': [2010,2012,2012,2013], 'group': ['DCM','NII','DCM','DCM']})
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Input:

```
     ID  date group
0  3001  2010   DCM
1  3001  2012   NII
2  3002  2012   DCM
3  3002  2012   DCM
```

Method:

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
     ID  date group
0  3001  2010   DCM
1  3001  2012   NII
```